# Provide a standard edit method for Events in Custom Calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I have created a custom Calendar in android, kept in sync with a remote server via SyncAdapter using a custom Account with a custom AccountType.

The sync works fine and my app on the device has an activity that allows the user to insert edit and delete events in my custom calendar.

The only "problem" is the usability, 
since the user wants to use the standard calendar app present on the device, because he's used to it's interface, etc.

Actually when I open my events from the standard calendar app, I can see the details of the event but there is no edit or delete function available.

In order to edit such appointments the user must close the standard calendar app, open my app (which should provide a list of the events and then edit them.)

Is it possible to let the system know that there is my App on the device with a specific Activity that is able to perform operations like edit or delete on the events belonging to my custom calendar which has a specific account type ?

Any Idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.